# How to add a synonym in solr which the word having comma?

Tags: solr

Generally we map synonyms in synonyms.txt like below
           -->the,teh,eh  and so on.

But i have a synonym like below
         -->10,000, ten thousand

since the 10,000 number has comma, it is unable to map.

can anyone let me know how to add this synonym

Thanks,

Subbarao.

Comment: Instead of using comma in synonymy, why don't you use filter to remove comma ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` before your comma, like: `10\,000`.

Comment: Hi Jack, thank you , I tried  but it is not working.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think this thread answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255172/solr-ignoring-comma-and-other-punctuation-while-searching

Comment: HI Jack can you help me one more scenario i.e  is this mapping valid 
  "10,000",ten thousand,   the main question here is will quotes valid in synonyms?

Comment: I do not think so, but I am not sure. But why would you do that?